# Which Gitlab runner do I need to use?

Tags: windows, gradle, heroku, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am making my yml file, but I keep struggeling with an error that I get. The error is:

> apt-get : The term 'apt-get' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again. At
> C:\Windows\TEMP\build_script267802092\script.ps1:217 char:1

I think the problem is that I do not have the correct runner to run this. The problem is that I do not know which runner is the correct runner for me.

I have tried using the shell runner, but that one gives me the error above.

My yml file:

```
image: node:latest


stages:
  # - build
  # - sonarqube-check
  # - test
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - master

sonarqube-check:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:jre11-slim
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script: ./gradlew sonarqube
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - master

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew check



deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=heroku-coalition --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  only:
  - master
    


after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

I am using a windows machine with windows 10 (if that information is needed)
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining which `image` to use in your yml, you should be using a docker executor.

Assuming you've already installed GitLab Runner following the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html), you can then add a runner with "docker" as the executor. Here's a link to the [docs](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-your-opencv-flask-web-application-on-heroku-c23efcceb1e8)

Docker should already be installed on your server as well.

Comment: What do you mean with Docker should be already installed on my server? Do I need to install docker on my laptop or where should it be installed?

Comment: Docker should be installed wherever you runner is, if you have the gitlab-runner installed on your gitlab server, you should install docker there as well.